# quick way to add chrome (or internet) shortcuts to home screens

Tags: chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts

On  the iphone, under the Safari settings, there was an option ADD TO HOME SCREEN.

that gets quite handy to have direct bookmarks launchable from a single tap on the icon. 
How do you do that in the android world?

I got a note 3 & I'm dying to get this functionality in.

http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

Comment: Would the "bookmarks" widget be sufficient? AFAIK that's available by default, and you can pick the desired bookmark from your stored ones.

Comment: I uninstalled TouchWiz ROM so I'm not sure, on stock you can add > Shortcut > Contact  and then select dial or message each person you add. Also there's many widgets on the play store too for contacts etc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Chrome, first add the site you're interested in as a bookmark by clicking the little star icon. Then go to **Bookmarks** (from Chrome's menu), and long-tap the bookmark you just created. A context menu appears, and the bottom item is **Add to home screen**. If you like, first click **Edit bookmark** to set the label the bookmark will use: it defaults to the web page title, which isn't always what you want.

If Samsung is still shipping their own browser in the Note 3, the procedure is the same there, but the bookmarks icon is a kind of banner with a star, and the menu item is called **Add shortcut to home**.

---

### Update March 2017

The above is now more than three years old, and the Chrome UI has changed since then. You can't add a bookmark to the home screen that way any more. Now, you need to visit the bookmark in Chrome, bring up the menu (three-dots icon in the top right), and choose **Add to home screen**.

The method of using Chrome's bookmarks widget still works. Long-tap the home screen, choose "Widgets", scroll down to Chrome in the alphabetic list, and drag the bookmarks widget to the desired place.

Comment: I don't get a context menu when I long tap the bookmark, and see no option to add bookmark to homescreen. I have android 5.0. Is this normal?

Comment: @the_prole I've updated my answer for Chrome's current behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

**How to do it from the default Browser:**

- If it is not yet in your bookmarks:

  Go to browser > go to website > Menu: [Save to bookmarks] > On the bookmark page under [Add to] select Homescreen instead of Bookmarks.
- If it is already in your bookmarks:

  Go to browser > Menu [Bookmarks] > long-press on bookmark > in pop-up menu select [Add shortcut to home]

**How to do it from the desktop:**

Long Press Desktop > Add a widget > select Bookmark > select website from bookmark